# Testing a test function decorator

Tags: python, django

How do I test a decorator which is used solely for django's TestCase methods? I have a decorator which creates admin user and logs user in to a test client:

```
def create_admin_user_and_login(func):                                                                                                                                                                       
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self):
        faker = Faker()
        username = faker.pronounceable_unique_id(length=30)
        password = faker.password()
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=username,
            first_name=faker.word().title(),
            last_name=faker.word().title(),
            email=faker.email(),
            password=password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        self.client.login(username=username, password=password)
        return func(self)
    return wrapper
```

Where `Faker()` is a fake data generator, unrelated to the subject. I use this decorator like this:

```
class SomeUnitTest(TestCase):
    @create_admin_user_and_login
    def test_login_required(self):
        self.assertContains(self.client.get(reverse('some_url')), 'logged in')
```

How do I test this decorator? I looked at cpython source code for answers, but I couldn't find my usage case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are no conventional solutions suggested, I went for a simple solution:

```
class HelpersTest(TestCase):

    @helpers.create_admin_user_and_login
    def test_create_admin_user_and_login(self):
        self.assertIn('_auth_user_id', self.client.session)
        user = User.objects.get(pk=self.client.session['_auth_user_id'])
        self.assertTrue(user.is_staff)
        self.assertTrue(user.is_superuser)
```

I assume I might have some issues with `coverage.py` catching that, but that's not a major factor.

UPDATE: No issues with `coverage.py`, solution works just perfectly.